# Identifying which parameter is sent to the function

Tags: javascript

there is a function where the definition states 3 parameters.

**ex:**

```
function func(param1,param2,param3){
   //does somethings
}
```

I would like to call that same function with just providing the third parameter only. The solution I though of is the following.

```
func(undefined,undefined,valueForParam3);
```

I don't think this is the proper way to handle such a scenario. Providing that I've handled `undefined` in the function implementation where it sets defaults. Please guide me on this.

Comment: "I don't think this is the propper way to handle such a scenario." — That **is** the proper way to handle it.

Comment: Isn't setting undefined would confuse another developer is he's debugging?

Comment: If they can't handle idiomatic JS then that's their problem.

Comment: If all parameters are optional, some may consider it better design to define only one parameter that receives an object.